# How can I fasten the "histc" Matlab function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, local, histogram

I need to fasten this part of my Matlab code :

```
 double(sum(histc(windows, 0:1:255),2)')
```

It is applied on every pixel of a large image, it is for calculating the local histogram (within 'windows') so it is very quite consuming.

Do you have any suggestion to fasten the computing ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit the overlap between adjacent pixels. Lets say you us a window of size 3x3 and have calculated the histogram for a pixel I(x,y), then the histogram for pixel I(x+1,y) will contain 6 of the same pixels. So you need only subtract 3 values and add 3.

Your code looks wrong. histc returns bin counts and then you sum the counts which should always add up to the size of your window. Do you want to calculate the sum of pixel intensities within the window? Then you should just use the sum function directly.